# Is there a computable model of ZFC?

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, set-theory

**Background**

Assuming ZFC is consistent, then by downward Löwenheim–Skolem, there is a countable model (M,$\in$) of ZFC. Since the universe M is countable, we may as well think of it as actually being the set of natural numbers, so $\in$ will be some binary relation on the natural numbers.

> Can such a relation ever be computable?

**Partial results**

<del>One can show that the class of binary relations $R$ on the natural numbers such that $(\mathbb{N},R) \models ZFC$ forms a $\Pi_0^1$ class, and will be nonempty so long as ZFC is consistent. This already gives us some interesting results. For example, by the low basis theorem, there is a low $R$ such that $(\mathbb{N},R) \models ZFC$. But I have been unable to determine whether such a function can be made computable; the best I can do is show that if such a function is computable, then there is no effective way of finding, given a finite set D of natural numbers, the element n such that D={m : mRn}.</del>

Comment: It's not a closed set, so not a pi 0 1 class...

Comment: You're right of course; I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: maybe you were thinking of complete extensions of ZFC

Comment: Anyway, this is what inspired the question at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/266648/models-of-zfc-and-the-borel-hierarchy

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The Tennenbaum phenomenon is amazing, and that is totally correct, but let me give a direct proof using the idea of [computable inseparability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effectively_separable).

**Theorem**. There is no computable model of ZFC.

Proof: Suppose to the contrary that M is a computable model of ZFC. That is, we assume that the underlying set of M is ω and the membership relation E of M is computable.

First, we may overcome the issue you mention at the end of your question, and we can computably get access to what M thinks of as the 
n<sup>th</sup> natural number, for any natural number n. To see this, observe first that there is a particular natural number z, which M believes 
is the natural number 0, another natural number N, which M believes to the set of all natural numbers, and another natural number s, which M 
believes is the successor function on the natural numbers. By decoding what it means to evaluate a function in set theory using ordered pairs, We 
may now successively compute the function i(0)=z and i(n+1) = the unique number that M believes is the successor function s of i(n). Thus, 
externally, we now have computable access to what M believes is the n<sup>th</sup> natural number. Let me denote i(n) simply by **n**. (We 
could computably rearrange things, if desired, so that these were, say, the odd numbers).

Let A, B be any [computably inseparable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effectively_separable) sets. That is, A and B are disjoint computably 
enumerable sets having no computable separation. (For example, A is the set of TM programs halting with output 0 on input 0, and B is the set of 
programs halting with output 1 on input 0.) Since A and B are each computably enumerable, there are programs p<sub>0</sub> and p<sub>1</sub> that 
enumerate them (in our universe). These programs are finite, and M agrees that **p<sub>0</sub>** and **p<sub>1</sub>** are TM programs that 
enumerate a set of what it thinks are natural numbers. There is some particular natural number c that M thinks is the set of natural numbers 
enumerated by **p<sub>0</sub>** before they are enumerated by **p<sub>1</sub>**. Let A<sup>+</sup> = { n | **n** E c }, which is the set 
of natural numbers n that M thinks are enumerated into M's version of A before they are enumerated into M's version of B. This is a computable 
set, since E is computable. Also, every member of A is in A<sup>+</sup>, since any number actually enumerated into A will be seen by M to have 
been so. Finally, for the same reason, no member of B is in A<sup>+</sup>, because M can see that they are enumerated into B by a (standard) 
stage, when they have not been enumerated into A. Thus, A<sup>+</sup> is a computable separation of A and B, a contradiction. QED

Essentially this argument also establishes the version of Tennenbaum's theorem mentioned by Anonymous, that there is no computable nonstandard 
model of PA. But actually, Tennenbaum proved a stronger result, showing that *neither* plus nor times individually is computable in a nonstandard model of PA. And this takes a somewhat more subtle argument.

**Edit (4/11/2017).** The question was just bumped by another edit, and so I thought it made sense to update my answer here by mentioning a generalization of the result. Namely, in recent joint work,

- M. T. Godziszewski and J. D. Hamkins, [Computable quotient presentations of models of arithmetic and set theory](http://jdh.hamkins.org/computable-quotient-presentations-of-models-of-arithmetic-and-set-theory/), click through for pdf at the arxiv.

we prove that not only is there no computable model of ZFC, but also there is no computable quotient presentation of a model of ZFC, and indeed there is no c.e. quotient presentation of such a model, by an equivalence relation of any complexity. That is, there is no c.e. relation $\hat\in$ and equivalence relation $E$, of any complexity, which is a congruence with respect to $\hat\in$, such that the quotient $\langle\mathbb{N},\hat\in\rangle/E$ is a model of ZFC.

Comment: I agree that if we could compute the function i, that would be enough to prove that there is no computable model of ZFC. However, I still don't buy the argument that i is computable. I have the same problem as I did with the previous answer. In order to compute i(n+1) from i(n), we must find the unique number m such that (the number corresponding to) the set {i(n),{i(n),m}} is in s. If the function that, given input i(n),m, returned the number corresponding to the ordered pair (i(n),m) then we would be in great shape, but I don't see any reason why this function should be computable.

Comment: But you have the number N, of which the E predecessors are precisely what M thinks of as the natural numbers, and this makes things easier. To get even easier, don't use the usual pairing function, but just think of s as the set of pairs of adjacent natural numbers. With this pairing function, x E N, there is precisely one y such that {x,y} E s. That is, there is precisely one y such that there is w E s with x E w and y E w. This y is i(x). But you can do essentially the same thing with the usual pairing function.

Comment: Well, if you use that easier pairing function, you also have to exclude the already-used value below x. So I should say, precisely one y not-yet-used for which...

Comment: Basically, the function i is computable because you can go and search for the unique element of s that encodes the pair (i(n),y). You will eventually find it, since it is really there. So look at all w for which w E s, and then look at all g,h E w, etc. unwrapping the usual pairing code.

Comment: Gregory Igusa points out why the ordered pairing function is computable (actually, "computable enough"): pretend we have a set A of all two element sets. Then, given n and m, we can compute the ordered pair (n,m) by first finding a set y in A containing both n and m, and then finding a set x in A containing both n and y. Then x is the ordered pair (n,m). Of course, A is not actually a set, so this function isn't quite computable, but given any set X, there is a set of all two-element subsets of X, which lets you compute the ordered pair of any two elements of X, which is good enough.

Comment: This is essentially what I have been saying. Since we have the number s, which M thinks consists precisely of the successor pairs, it serves the same purpose as your set A.

Comment: The difficulty is that we don't have a set of "all w for which w E s", since we can see when something is in s, and not in s, but there's no general way of knowing that nothing else is in s. However, the solution to this is to look at a set* of all two-element sets. If s is in this set, then you know to stop looking for more elements once you have found two.

*This doesn't, of course, exist, since it is a class rather than a set, but if you intersect it with a large enough set you are fine.

Comment: But the set of all w such that w E s is enumerable, since E is a computable relation on omega. So we just try out more and more w until we find the one we want. Since M thinks everything in s is a pair, and that s is a function, we won't ever find some wrong w that deceives us. I don't think there is any problem with this.

Comment: I don't think you need the fancy definition of $A^{+}$.  Just let c be the natural number representing A in M (i.e. those elements which M thinks p_0 converges on)  Since it's a theorem of ZFC that p_0 and p_1 are disjoint you shouldn't need the fancy enters p_0 before p_1 stuff.

Comment: @Peter, yes, for those particular computably inseparable sets, we know that $p_0$ and $p_1$ provably enumerate disjoint sets. I agree.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins "since any number actually enumerated into A will be seen by M to have been so" -- Is this because $\Sigma_1$-formulas conserve upwards, and $\mathbb{N}$ embeds as an initial segment in every model of PA? (Just checking if I understand the argument)

Comment: @Jori Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 18):

This can also be done using Godel-Roesser instead of Tennebaum.  Suppose M is a  model of ZFC.  There is an element $a$ of that M believes is the set of Godel codes for the sentences true of the integers of M. Of course $a$ may contain nonstandard Godel codes, but if we let T be the set of standard sentences with Godel codes in $a$, then T will be a complete consistent extension of Peano Arithmetic.  If M is computable, then T would be computable, but there are no computable complete consistent extensions of Peano Arithmetic.

Of course the appeal to Godel-Roesser just hides Joel's argument about recursive inseparable r.e. sets.

Comment: Good to see that you and your evil twin have merged ...

Comment: Is there are similar argument for the normal Tennenbaum result? So about nonstandard models of PA, not ZFC.

Answer (score 15):

No, it cannot be computable.  It's a theorem of Tennenbaum from the 50's that there is no computable, non-standard model of Peano arithmetic.  If there were a computable model of ZFC, then it would give a computable, non-standard model of Peano arithmetic.  Specifically, it would contain some non-standard model for PA, specified by a set of elements and two relations, and the computability of the model of ZFC would imply computability there.  (If, say, you want the sum of elements a and b in the model of PA, search by brute force for an element c of the model such that (a,b,c) is in the sum relation.  This may be terribly slow, but it will eventually terminate.)

Edit: That's a good point about the computability of (a,b,c), and I'm not sure how to compute that.  Fortunately, it turns out not to be needed here.  Specifically, if we define (a,b,c) = ((a,b),c) and define (u,v) = {{u}, {u,v}}, then even though it's not clear whether you can computably produce (a,b,c) given a, b, and c, given something you know a priori is a triple, you can try to check whether it comes from a,b,c by finding appropriate elements.  (In the simpler case of pairs, to check whether w = (u,v) given that it is some ordered pair, we just need to find x and y such that both are in w, u is in x, and u and v are in y.)  Now we just do major brute force: not only searching over all possible choices of c, but also over the auxiliary elements that would establish that (a,b,c) is in the relation.  I hope there's a nicer way to do this, but I think it works.

Comment: Doesn't that require that, given a, b, and c, you have a way of finding the triple (a,b,c) in order to determine whether it is in the sum relation? If the function that takes you from a, b, c to the ordered triple (a,b,c) is not computable, I don't see how this gives a contradiction. In other words, I don't see how you can conclude from the mere fact that you have a computable model of ZFC that you have a computable nonstandard model of PA.

Comment: I explain this issue in my answer. You do find a computable model as Anonymous says.

Comment: What makes the model of PA necessarily non-standard?

Comment: @David Feldman: a standard model would have to include subsets of $\omega$ such as $0'$, which are not computable.

Comment: @CarlMummert Not every nonstandard model of PA or ZFC needs to encode $0'$, since there are models whose standard system consists entirely of low sets. But they will encode non-computable sets, and this is enough to support the argument that they cannot be themselves computable.

Comment: @Joel: definitely. I think I was only responding to the question in the previous comment, "why can't the model be standard?" - why can't it be an $\omega$-model?

Comment: Ah, I see that I had mis-read your comment.