A property of < in Primitive recursive arithmetic
In Primitive recursive arithmetic (PRA), we can introduce $\lt$ by introducing its representing function $K_{\lt}$, where $K_{\lt}(x,y) =sg(x+1-y)$. Here "sg" and "-" are the functions defined by $sg(0)=0\land sg(x+1)=1$,  $pred(0)=0\land pred(x+1)=x$ and $a-0=a\land  a-(b+1)=pred(a-b)$.
In this situation, I want to prove in PRA that if $K_{\lt}(x,y+1)=0$, then $K_{\lt}(x,y)=0\lor x=y$.
If $K_{\lt}(x,y+1)=0$, then $sg( (x+1)-(y+1))=sg(pred(x+1-y))=0$. Note that by the induction axiom $sg(x)=0\to x=0$ and $pred(x)=0\to x=0\lor x=1$. Hence we have $x+1-y=0\lor x+1-y=1$. If $x+1-y=0$, then $sg(x+1-y)=0$, so $K_{\lt}(x,y)=0$.
But, I do not know how to prove in PRA with those recursive defining equations that if $x+1-y=1$, then $x=y$. Is it necessary to adopt this as a new axiom?
I know that PRA is strong enough to prove the Gödel incompleteness theorems and many other logical consequnces, and these logical results are proved by introducing new primitive recursive functions with those recursive defining equations. In this point, I want to know whether those recursive defining equations are strong enough to deduce basic properties like "If $x+1-y=1$, then $x=y$" and even "If $pred(a)=1$, then $a=2$".

Crossposted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4944796/28111

Generally I recommend not cross-posting until at least a week has passed with no answer.

Could someone tell me whether we can make badly behaved nonstandard models of PRA as easily as for, say, Robinson's Q? In that theory you can just adjoin a point or two at infinity and make things strange. Does this method work in PRA as well? If so, the answer here will be negative.

@JoelDavidHamkins Since PRA has induction + injectivity of successor, that shouldn't work. (More substantively, see Francois Dorais' answer at the MSE version.)

@NoahSchweber Oh, I had thought that PRA specifically did not have induction. Isn't that the point of it, that it is weak that way? I thought we just have the recursive definitions of the primitive recursive functions, and that's it. Of course if you have induction then the whole question here is easy. (Meanwhile, having one point at infinity that is self-successor does not violate injectivity of successor, but you can't make a model of PRA this way, since the parity function won't work.) But how easily can we make nonstandard models of PRA?

For example, does the Tennenbaum theorem hold for nonstandard models of PRA? That would be decisive negative answer to my inquiry.

This answer seems to claim that PRA includes $\text{IE}_1$ and has no computable nonstandard models. https://mathoverflow.net/a/121252/1946

@JoelDavidHamkins  PRA can be viewed as a definitional expansion of the theory obtained by augementing the theort $\mathrm{I}\Delta_0$ with axioms $\phi_n$ (for $n\in\omega$), such that $\varphi_0$ asserts the totality of exponentiation, $\varphi_1$ asserts the totality of superexponentiation (tetration), etc.

I see, I hadn't realized that it included $I\Delta_0$. Thanks!  (And apologies for all my poorly informed comments on this thread.)
