# Models of ZFC and the Borel hierarchy

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

The collection of

*binary relations $R$ on the natural numbers such that $(\mathbb{N},R) \models ZFC$*

forms a Borel set, neither closed nor open -- assuming Con(ZFC).

- Can you show it's not $F_\sigma$ or $G_\delta$?
- Is it actually complete for level $\omega$ of the Borel hierarchy?

Comment: Usually, "complete for X" means (1) in X and (2) at least as complicated as anything else in X. Presumably, by "in some sense complete for finite levels of the Borel hierarchy", you meant only (2).

Comment: "Complete for level $\omega$" looks plausible.

Comment: I think that Sam Coskey was looking at the isomorphism relation on these models under Borel reducibility, aiming to place it in the hierarchy of Borel reducibility.

Comment: By reading the axioms (i.e. every axiom is satisfied, as a formalized statement) it's a $\Pi^0_{\omega+1}$ set (since satisfying a first-order sentence is $\Pi^0_n$ for some $n$). I think that it's not $\Pi^0_n$ for $n<\omega$ amounts to the fact that ZFC is not finitely axiomatizable.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais Why not expand your comment to an answer?

Comment: My student Samuel Dworetzky showed that the isomorphism relation for countable models of ZFC is Borel complete (in the sense of Borel complexity theory). I don't think it affects this particular question, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@FrançoisG.Dorais commented:

> By reading the axioms (i.e. every axiom is satisfied, as a formalized statement) it's a $\Pi^0_{\omega+1}$ set (since satisfying a first-order sentence is $\Pi^0_n$ for some $n$). I think that it's not $\Pi^0_n$ for $n<\omega$ amounts to the fact that ZFC is not finitely axiomatizable.

Comment: Can someone turn this from a vague impression into a proof? This is an interesting question, and I don't  think this comment answers it.